# TYPO3: Disable deletion of records

Tags: typo3, backend, records

Is it possible to prevent the deletion of Records in the TYPO3 backend of certain tables from an own Extension?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the delete column from the TCA configuration? Or is the record then dropped from DB?

Answer (score 1):

In PageTS there is an option disableDelete.[table] which disables delete icons in TceForm. So you can specify this for certain backend users or groups.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/UserTsconfig/Options/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

Since I work with TYPO3 6.2, "options.disableDelete" does not work with me.
This was / is a bug that was fixed 3 months ago in TYPO3 7.6.

Answer (score -1):

The short question is no. There is no such setting.

The long question is: Sure, you just need to use the hook `processCmdmap`of the DataHandler and return `$commandIsProcessed` with `false`.